# Google+ Games Buttons

Tags: button, html

I have no idea how to even start this question, but I was referred to Stack Overflow by a friend who basically told me that anything I need help with or to help others, I should come here. So I have a question for website designers and coders alike. (optional: have a google+ account for a visual aid)

If you go into Google+, you have all these cool features that seem advanced with code, but very basic in style. You hover over a button and it becomes animated like the in the games section. You have an image of the game in a div container I believe and it cycles through like its a gif or a timed sequence. At the bottom of the image, you see a small box from left to right, filled in with a different color, and has the name of the game on it. When you hover over said game a box begins to move from the bottom of the div to the top of the div completely covering up the image, but has more details in it. These details includes the description of the game and a button at the bottom that is a dark bluish that says play game, and when you hover over it, then it becomes a light blue like color.

Basically I want to create the same thing, but with different attributes. Same concept initially with the picture and the box with the name with a white border, but when you hover over it, then the background would be like a dark red with white text and a dark red button with a white border with the words view site and when you hover over it then it is like a light red.

I am making a portfolio website for my website designs and photoshop work. I think that this would be a great addition and I hope somebody or anyone can help me. I always give credit in my about pages if I didn't actually create something on my own.

Thank you for your time on reading this ridicuously long question, but I hope it relatively makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question makes sense and you can totally do it, personally I recommend learning HTML & CSS and creating a working demo - then hiring someone / finding someone to help build the features you want it to have. That way you have total control of the appearance, which I think is something that you're more interested about then coding the features ( you mention showcasing your design work ).

> http://learn.shayhowe.com/html-css/terminology-syntax-intro/

Is a nice resource I saw today that might help you get started. In the future I think Stack Overflow is much more affective for specific questions related to specific issues, not something so broad as to code and design an entire web application.

Best of luck!

Comment: Thank you for the answer I will totally check that out. I also have another question: I have been googling tags that I could think of, but nothing relates to what I am looking to build or to start off from, like a demo. Do you have any suggestions regarding that?